# How to set default Paragraph format to Normal(DIV) in CKEditor 4.x?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

When **autoParagraph** config in CKEditor 4 is set to 'true' or not set at all, I see **Paragraph format** is set to Normal(DIV) by default.

When **autoParagraph** config in CKEditor 4 is set to 'false', how can I set Paragraph Format to Normal(DIV) by default? I am not finding a way to do that in CKEditor 4.

**JS Fiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/2c6jasv4/

```
configs:

function editorConfig() {
    return {
     autoParagraph: false,
     enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV,
     format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div",
     fillEmptyBlocks :true
    }
}

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', editorConfig());

HTML:
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">When autoParagraph config is set to false, how can I set Format as Normal(DIV) by default?</textarea>
```

If I select Paragraph Format as Normal DIV manually, it will add `<div>` for the text without needing a ENTER. So, I am looking for a way to set Normal DIV as default paragraph format.

When autoParagraph is not disabled, default format seen in Normal DIV.